# Correction of data using a correlation

Tags: regression, psychometrics, cross-correlation

Suppose I have measured the outcome variable ***A*** using a (psychophysical) test that determines the ability of a subject to discriminate between two stimuli with a certain difference (the variable ***X***). It was a two-alternative forced choice task, meaning that the subjects choose in each trial if the stimuli were diferent, yes or no. Now, dependent on the variable ***X***, the subjects scored at minimum 50% (meaning they were guessing at small x) up to 100% (always choosing correct alternative at large ***X***). The outcome variable ***A***, now, is the value of ***X*** where correct rates are 75% (midway between chance and 100% correct rates).

I have measured A on three points in time (before, during, after: *t0*, *t1*, *t2*). At *t0* no practice was received on the task, at *t1* ten minutes and at *t2* 20 minutes of practice was received (8 participants). A repeated measures ANOVA showed a significant effect of practice as the scores go up by around 33%.

Now, during testing I have sampled at random a condition in which the subjects could theoretically never have been able to do the task above chance level (very small ***X***), which are referred to as 'catch trials'. It turns out that these guess rates (theoretically 50%, i.e., chance level) increased significantly, being chance at *t0* (as expected), but steadily, and significantly increasing above 50% at *t1* (60%) and *t2* (70%). The most parsimonious explanation here is that subjects were doing the task using false cues. In other words, they noticed cues between the stimuli other than ***X***. This means that the learning effect of 33% is an overestimate.

Now, I plotted the individual improvement percentage (average 33% as noted above) against the corresponding guess rate pooling all data across *t0*, *t1*, *t2*. This, indeed, showed that ***A*** correlated significantly with guess rate. I did an *F*-test on the slope, P~0.01 and a correlation coefficient (*r*<sup>2</sup>) = 0.25.

**Can I, based on this data set, quantitatively correct the learning effect of 33%** by the finding that it, at least in part, was caused by the subjects using false cues? In other words, can I reduce the 33% learning improvement by a certain factor to correct for the subjects using other cues?

Is it as simple as subtracting the false-cue improvement (20%) from the total improvement (33%). Or should I take the 0.25 correlation coefficient into account as well?

*ps: as it is my first step in CrossValidated, please feel free to shoot at the question to improve it*

Comment: I know this is an old question :-) This is a curious situation, I wonder what your experiment actually was and what cue subjects manged to pick up that was not X. In any case, I would probably go back to estimating A, instead of "correcting it" afterwards. I.e. you probably are estimating A by fitting a logistic function to each subjects performance (?), and you could modify this procedure to account for the increased baseline performance (at X=0).

Comment: Apart from that, it's not very nice that you first find A for each subject, and then do further tests. It would be much neater to put everything into one statistical model, and fit mixed-model logistic regression directly accounting for practiceTime. But this becomes more involved, and I am guessing you have already finished this project anyway.

Comment: Hi Alice! I am wondering if you noticed my comments above? I can imagine that you are not interested in having this discussion here anymore, but then perhaps delete this question?